# Python Google Drive API not creating csv with list of all files within sub-folders

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of files with names, dates, etc into a `csv` file from files on my Google Drive folder which has around 15k sub-folders (one level below) within the main folder that have about 1-10 files each that amount to around 65k files in total.

I used the following code in Python to create my `csv` file which generates the information for all the sub-folders but only about 18k of the individual files within those sub-folders (the most recently uploaded files in those sub-folders).

I am not quite sure why my code is not able to get the list for all the files in those sub-folders. Is there a limit I am hitting that stops me from getting the information for all the files?

Note: The folder I am storing the files is a shared folder but I don't think that should be affecting anything.

```
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None
import pandas as pd

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'

folder_id = '########' # Set to id of the parent folder you want to list (should be the content folder)
folder_list = []
all_folders = []
file_list = []

def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.
    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.
    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,'drive-python-quickstart.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def get_root_folder(): # Gets folder list from original root folder
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    results = service.files().list(q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '"+folder_id+"' in parents",
        pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, mimeType)", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
    folders = results.get('files', [])
    if not folders:
        print('No folders found.')
    else:
        for folder in folders:
            id = folder.get('id')
            folder_list.append(id)

def get_all_folders(folder_list): # Creates list of all sub folder under root, keeps going until no folders underneath
    for folder in folder_list:
        additional_folders = []
        credentials = get_credentials()
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
        results = service.files().list(
            q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '" +folder+ "' in parents",
            pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, mimeType)", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])
        for item in items:
            id = item.get('id')
            additional_folders.append(id)
        if not additional_folders:
            pass
        else:
            all_folders.extend(additional_folders)
            folder_list = additional_folders
            get_all_folders(folder_list)

def merge(): # Merges sub folder list with full list
    global full_list
    full_list = all_folders + folder_list
    full_list.append(folder_id)

def get_file_list(): # Runs over each folder generating file list, for files over 1000 uses nextpagetoken to run additional requests, picks up metadata included in the request
    for folder in full_list:
        credentials = get_credentials()
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
        page_token = None
        while True:
            results = service.files().list(
                q="'" + folder + "' in parents",
                pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(name, md5Checksum, mimeType, size, createdTime, modifiedTime, id, parents, trashed)", pageToken=page_token, supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
            items = results.get('files', [])
            for item in items:
                name = item['name']
                checksum = item.get('md5Checksum')
                size = item.get('size', '-')
                id = item.get('id')
                mimeType = item.get('mimeType', '-')
                createdTime = item.get('createdTime', 'No date')
                modifiedTime = item.get('modifiedTime', 'No date')
                parents = item.get('parents')
                trashed = item.get('trashed')
                file_list.append([name, checksum, mimeType, size, createdTime, modifiedTime, id, parents, trashed])
            page_token = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break
    files = pd.DataFrame(file_list,columns=['file_name','checksum_md5','mimeType','size', 'date_created', 'date_last_modified','google_id', 'google_parent_id', 'trashed'])
    files.drop(files[files['trashed'] == True].index, inplace=True) #removes files which have True listed in trashed, these are files which had been moved to the recycle bin
    foldernumbers = files['mimeType'].str.contains('application/vnd.google-apps.folder').sum()
    filenumbers = (~files['mimeType'].str.contains('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')).sum()
    print('Number of folders is: ', foldernumbers)
    print('Number of files is: ', filenumbers)
    files.to_csv('D:/GoogleAPIMetadata.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Collecting folder id list')
    get_root_folder()
    get_all_folders(folder_list)
    merge()
    print('Generating file metadata list')
    get_file_list()
```

Comment: are the folders inside of folders and how many folders deep? because that could be an issue. Its hard to diagnose your issue as you haven't really given an example of the structure of the data and what files are not being found, relatively to the structure.

Comment: It's just one level down. So in this main folder, I have those 15,000 sub-folders and the files (images) are within those sub-folders.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I cannot understand your current situation. You cannot retrieve all files while you have already retrieved the folder list of all folders you expect? Or, you cannot retrieve both all files and all folders? And, about `The folder I am storing the files is a shared folder`, in this case, that is not the hard drive?

Comment: @Tanaike in my csv file, I have a list of both files and folders (sub-folders), but the sub-folders list is complete but it is incomplete for the files (only 18k out of the 65k files) within all those sub-folders. On your question about `the folder I am storing the files in a shared folder,` it just means that this is shared Google Drive folder and not one I created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that in your situation, you have already retrieved all folders, but you cannot retrieve all files from all folders. About `The folder I am storing the files is a shared folder`, in your situation, the files and folders are put in the shared Drive? Or, those files and folders are put in a folder in other user and those are shared with you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that I cannot retrieve the information for all the files within all the folders. And yes, the shared folder is created by another user and shared with me but I can create, delete and add files and folders within that shared folder.